# Setting up Nginx -- redirecting requests to a auth server and getting redirected back to serve the request

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, cookie

Any incoming request on (x.x.x.x.x)--> redirect to x.x.x.x.auth.domain.edu -- > that authenticates a user and redirects back to x.x.x.x server. (With a cookie set, In my case it is EZproxy server doing the cookie setting)

I have tried rewriting the request url and also using proxy_pass  booth resulting in looping error error (from browser).

I must be missing some basic header or something i am not able to get what since yesterday morning.
Any suggestions regarding how the config must be?

Comment: Show what you have done so far.

Comment: These are the different things that i have tried since yesterday. http://pastebin.com/xi3BVBE9

Answer (score 0):

Your `root` directive has two problems:

1. It uses a relative path. When a relative path is used, it's relative to a default directory compiled into nginx. Do you know which one that is? It's best to specify absolute paths.
2. It is in the wrong place. The `root` directive should be specified in the `server` block. This is one of the [most common nginx misconfigurations](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. But i am not getting how these both would contribute to  "server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.". That its not serving the request  after getting the redirected request

Comment: Did you _fix the problems_ and _clear your browser cache_?

Comment: Yes I did that.

Comment: OK, then show your corrected configuration.

Comment: Here is the new config fixing the relative path and the root http://pastebin.com/6JTXsbRq .. Thanks for suggestions was never aware of the practices,